# Navigation Bar - LI:HOVER Full Height

Tags: html, css, nav, navigationbar

So I want a navigation bar, with, when I hover over a li / a element, I get a different color for the FULL height of the navigation bar. Because when I hover over it, only the background-color of the text changes... which is quite ugly...

I hope this is clear enough, but the system blocks me uploading an image :o.

Thank You!

EDIT:
I forgot the HTML and CSS:

```
    <ul id="nav">
            <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Courses</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Subjects</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Sign Up</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Log In</a></li>
        </ul>

    #nav {
    height: 60px;
    font-size: 30px;
    line-height: 60px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #0080FF;
    width: auto;
    border: 10px solid #16044E;
    border-radius: 20px;
    z-index: 1;
}

#nav ul {
}

#nav li {
    display: inline;
    text-align: center;
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-right: 10px;
}

#nav li:hover {
    background-color: orange;
}

#nav a, a:active {
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Comment: could you upload a code snippet? (I.E.: JS Fiddle)

Comment: @AramilRey https://jsfiddle.net/g6eh4kro/

Comment: Are you looking for something like this http://jsfiddle.net/akshay7/grjdp7qw/ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The background color is applying to only the text background because you're using `display: inline;`

Any background give to inline element will apply to its content only, different from block element that will apply to the entire element.

The easiest solution is to change your display to `inline-block` like this:

```
#nav li
{
 display: inline-block;
}
```

[JSBin](http://jsbin.com/bazobi/1/edit?css,output)

Comment: I had to wait 7 minutes ^.^

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple solution change the background color on hover.

```
ul li a:hover {
background-color: blue;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add: `height: 100%;`

To: `#nav li {`

This should do it!

Comment: Woops, it has been solved already by @Anakin, it worked on my fiddle because I changed the display to inline-block!

Answer (score 0):

Add `display:inline-block` to the `a` and give it a height equal to the `nav`. I would suggest this as setting height on the li will make the text as a link.Setting it on the `a` will make the entire height link

```css
 #nav {
    height: 60px;
    font-size: 30px;
    line-height: 60px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #0080FF;
    width: auto;
    border: 10px solid #16044E;
    border-radius: 20px;
    z-index: 1;
}

#nav ul {
}

#nav li {
    display: inline;
    text-align: center;
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-right: 10px;
}

#nav li:hover a{
    background-color: orange;
}

#nav a, a:active {
    display:inline-block;
    height:60px;
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
 <ul id="nav">
            <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Courses</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Subjects</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Sign Up</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Log In</a></li>
        </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to set `display: inline-block` on your list items. Otherwise the items will behave like text elements (that's what `display: inline` does) and cannot have any other height outside `line-height`.

See this [pen](http://codepen.io/RadValentin/pen/mJyEvb?editors=010)